# Why is com.google.android.gsf.login warning me that I need to install Google Play Services?

Tags: application-autoupdate, google-play-services

This is a Nexus device running the latest stock OS version (v4.4.2), I already have Google Play Services installed (v4.2.43 according to the App Info in settings). Why is some unknown app asking me to update it? (I realise that the `com.google.android` part of the package name indicates that this probably an app made by Google that is probably part of their Google layer on top of AOSP Android, but why the odd error message and lack of proper app name)?

[image: An application requires installation of Google Play Services: Requested by com.google.android.gsf.login]

> **An application requires installation of Google Play Services**
>   Requested by com.google.android.gsf.login

What is `com.google.android.gsf.login` and why should I do what it is asking? It doesn't have a [store page](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gsf.login) and it doesn't appear in my apps list with that name. A bit of investigation with [Android System Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.electricsheep.asi)'s more detailed Apps view shows that Google Services Framework is `com.google.android.gsf` and the Google Account Manager is the `com.google.android.gsf.login` that we're looking for.

[image: com.google.android.gsf in ASI]
[image: com.google.android.gsf.login in ASI]

Clicking the notification from Android's notification bar takes me to the Play Store's page for Google Play Services where the latest version mentioned in the "What's New" section is 4.2.42, which is older than what I've already got installed, and I don't have an Update button (which suggests I'm already running the latest version).

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar issue on my Nexus 4 device, here is what I did to stop the issue:

Go to your 'Settings' menu, then go to 'Accounts'. Select 'Google' and check which google service has a sync issue. If you cant see any apps with sync issues, you will have to do as user 'Laural H' mentioned above: disable them all, and re-enable them one by one, checking that it syncs properly (before enabling the next one). When you find the app with sync issues, open the problematic app and login with your google credentials.

Answer (score 1):

You could try installing the newest version of [Google Play](http://handheld.softpedia.com/get/Business/Shopping/Android-Market-121182.shtml)
. If you don't want to do that, try one of these:

1. Go to Settings->Accounts->Google->Sync Data and disable all your Google Account sync items individually. Then enable the App Data and try again before enabling the rest of your sync items.
2. Go to Settings->Apps->Menu->clear app preferences.
3. Clearing the Play cache.

Comment: Link is now broken.